How to forbid unknown parameter type in a scalikejdbc query?
When writing a string interpolation with sql"", how can I make sure that a Binder is present for a given parameter type instead of using the default that might not do what I want?
For example
case class MyClass(id: String)
val param = MyClass("param")
// I would like a compilation error on the following line if there is no Binder for MyClass
sql"SELECT column FROM table WHERE id = ${param}"


I don't believe that's possible with SQLInterpolation because it seems to use Any for all parameters and pass parameters of non-natively handled types to java.sql.PreparedStatement.setObject directly. However, there is QueryDSL that provides type-safety that you're looking for.
An example from ScalikeJDBC 2.4.0 release notes:
scala> case class Name(value: String)
defined class Name

scala> val name = Name("Alice")
name: Name = Name(Alice)

scala> select.from(User as u).where.eq(u.name, name)
<console>:30: error: Could not find an implicit value of the ParameterBinderFactory[Name].
       select.from(User as u).where.eq(u.name, name)

